# NDB Model containing Blobstore key as attribute fails to_dict()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class Door(ndb.Model):
    key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(required=True)
    locked = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

I need to convert door to a dictionary as in: `door.to_dict()`

But it fails saying:

```
BlobKeyProperty Reference is not json serializable
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you are doing it correct (as far as to `to_dict()` is regarded), apart from the part Tim Hoffman mentioned about the key. Thats a mistake.

Just for future reference if a property is not convertible to json then you need to convert it your self.

eg dates are not convertible automatically to json because the converted would not know into what date format to convert them:

```
class Door(ndb.Model):
    creation_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    locked = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

do:

`door.to_dict(exclude=['creation_date'])`

and then find a way to convert the date to the format you need and append it to the created dict.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `key` as a property name.  `key` is an already defined accessor for the models key.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use key as a property on your door model. What is the key referencing? A different model? If so, use other_model = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(required=True).

If you want the door's key in your to_dict response, just override the to_dict() method:

class Door(ndb.Model):
    other_model = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(required=True)
    locked = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)

```
def to_dict(self, *args, **kwargs):
    d = super(Door, self).to_dict(args, kwargs)
    if 'key' not in d:
        d['key'] = self.key
    return d
```

If you are doing this to return a json response, I find the following more usesful. Write your own jsonEncoder. I do this:

```
import json
import webapp2
import datetime
import calendar
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class jsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return calendar.timegm(obj.utctimetuple())

        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return calendar.timegm(obj.timetuple())

        # If it is a key, return it in it's urlsafe format
        elif isinstance(obj, ndb.Key):
            return obj.urlsafe()

        elif isinstance(obj, ndb.Model):
            d = obj.to_dict()
            if obj.key is not None:
                d['key'] = obj.key.urlsafe()
            return d

        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            pass

        elif isinstance(obj, datastore_types.BlobKey):
            pass

        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Then, I create a JsonHandler:

```
class JsonHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, request, response):
        super(JsonHandler, self).initialize(request, response)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    def render_response(self, **context):
        return self.response.write(json.dumps(context, cls=jsonEncoder))
```

Finally, subclass the JsonHandler:

```
class DoorHandler(JsonHandler):
    def get(self):
        door = Door.query().get()
        return self.render_response(door=door)
```

Then you don't have to override the to_dict method and will work for all kinds of data.

Comment: I think I am using the same approach in my apps with the JSON handler. Nice!